camera2 CameraCaptureSession.capture() fails on first go but completes on second call
class AutomaticCapture(private val arguments: IntentArguments,
                       override val cameraCharacteristics: CameraCharacteristics,
                       override val imageReader: ImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(arguments.resX, arguments.resY, if (arguments.rawImage) ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR else ImageFormat.JPEG, 2)) : Capture {

    override fun takeCapture(cameraDevice: CameraDevice, cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession, handler: Handler) {
        Log.d("DebugInfo", "takeCapture() Automatic")
        val captureRequest = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
        captureRequest.addTarget(imageReader.surface)
        captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_STILL_CAPTURE)

        captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
        captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, arguments.orientation)

        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureRequest.build(), object: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureCompleted(
                session: CameraCaptureSession,
                request: CaptureRequest,
                result: TotalCaptureResult
            ) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
                Log.d("DebugInfo", "Automatic Capture completed. RawImage: ${arguments.rawImage}")
                var image: Image? = null

                //Have to wait for image to become available on imageReader
                while (image == null) {
                    image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage()
                }

                when (arguments.rawImage) {
                    true -> RawFileSaver().saveFileToLocation(image, arguments.filePath, arguments.fileName, cameraCharacteristics, result)
                    false -> JpegFileSaver().saveFileToLocation(image, arguments.filePath, arguments.fileName)
                }

                if (!arguments.doNotSaveJson) {
                    JsonFileSaver().saveCaptureResultToJson(arguments, result)
                }

                imageReader.close()
            }

            override fun onCaptureFailed(
                session: CameraCaptureSession,
                request: CaptureRequest,
                failure: CaptureFailure
            ) {
                super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure)
                Log.d("DebugInfo", "Automatic Capture failed. Reason: ${failure.reason}, rawImage: ${arguments.rawImage}, wasImageCaptured: ${failure.wasImageCaptured()}")
                takeCapture(cameraDevice, cameraCaptureSession, handler)
            }
        }, handler)
    }
}

    fun openCamera() {
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId,
            object: CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    Log.d("DebugInfo", "Inside openCamera()")
                    cameraDevice = camera

                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(capture.imageReader.surface),
                        object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                                cameraCaptureSession = session

                                //Take capture here when everything is set and configured
                                capture.takeCapture(cameraDevice, session, handler)
                                //exit Activity here.
                                finish()
                            }                      

                            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                                Log.d("DebugInfo", "onConfigureFailed()")
                                cameraDevice.close() }
                        }, handler)
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    Log.d("DebugInfo", "onDisconnected()")
                    camera.close()
                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                    Log.d("DebugInfo", "onError() with error: $error")
                    camera.close()
                }
            }, handler)
    }

I have a camera device that goes to onCaptureFailed() after the first try and manages to succeed after the second call to the takeCapture()-function inside the onCaptureFailed(). After the second call it goes onCaptureCompleted() and all goes well after that.
This code works on most devices I have tested but on one particular device it somehow needs to fail first once before succeeding. It takes about 4-5 seconds before the onCaptureFailed() gets called. The reason for failure is REASON_ERROR defined in CaptureFailure-class.
I have tried to prepare the captureSession and call onSurfacePrepared() but that didn't change the outcome. I have also tried to captureRequest.build() and then sleep the Thread for a while but that also didn't do anything.
I find it really interesting behaviour that somehow the second call always succeeds after the capture has failed once.
So the questions that I have are:

Is there a fix to this or reasons why this happens?
And where does the 4-5 seconds capture fail timeout come from? It seems like it could be set to a shorter amount but I haven't managed to find anywhere how and where.

EDIT:
The problem seems to occurring only on this specific camera device. The solution I used was to refactor all code to use new SessionConfiguration's and start capturing image's with cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest()-method and check when the imageReader's image size has grown. After this you could be certain that next capture will succeed and then you can use cameraCaptureSession.capture()-method to capture the final image.
So all-in-all even though onConfigured()-was called this specific camera device was not fully functional to actually capture images. This can be overcome with determining when the device is actually fully ready, in my case it was to start capturing images and see when the image size has grown from the first capture taken inside setRepeatingRequest().
